# Disabling inputs with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying to disable some input fields using jQuery 1.4.2. This is a part of the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="nume" value="Text" />
```

This is the Javascript:

```
$('.salveaza').live('click', function(e){
    $.get(ajaxURL, $('form', itemCurent).serialize()+'&id='+itemCurent.data('id')+'&optiune=editeaza-categorie');

    // This is the code for disabeling inputs
    $('input', itemCurent).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    itemCurent.removeClass('curent');
    $('.optiuniEditeaza', itemCurent).remove();

    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

The above code doesn't work. Note that the inputs are added with jQuery, that's why I am using live, I tried all sorts of stuff.

I also tried firebug console to disable all input fields on the page and it's not working:

```
$('input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Any help will be apreciated,
Thanks

Comment: That would seem to be the correct procedure for disabling an `input` element, as long as the `input` is a child of `itemCurent`. Are you certain that the code after your `$.get()` is running? Does the request succeed?

Comment: Yes the input is a child of itemCurent, I also tried disabling all the inputs on the page and it just enables all of them.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

Disable: `$('#the-field-id').attr('disabled', true);`

Enable: `$('#the-field-id').removeAttr('disabled');`

Comment: At your input field, You must set an ID or class to call that action!

[ $('#something') -> call ID "something" ]                

[ $('.something') -> call class "something" ]                 

[  # -> for ID  ]  [  . -> for Class  ]

Answer (score 2):

Use `true` instead of `disabled`:

```
$("input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bEC8L/ (input is set to disable after 5 seconds)

jQuery sets properties instead of attributes if the given attribute is actually a property name, and `"disabled"` isn't a valid value for the `disabled` property.

Comment: I tried using true and it's not working, I used the code you gived me and it enables all the inputs instead of disabling them.

Comment: @andreeib: Did you check the working example via the link I posted?  I just tested it in several browsers.  Your issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I checked your example and it's working, I used the console and I disabled the inputs on this stackoverflow page but when I want to disable the inputs on my page I just end up enabling them all.

Thank's for your quick answer.

Comment: @andreeib: Were you copy/pasting directly?  Make sure you're not passing a string as the second argument to `.attr()`, it has to be a boolean (`true`).

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code seems ok, so the problem must be coming from another part of code. Put a break on the line where you disable and then run step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Onclick of button the textbox will be disabled.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fname").attr("disabled",false);
        $("#idDisable").click(function(){

            $("#fname").attr("disabled",true);

        });

    });
</script>

    <input type="button" id="idDisable" value="click to disable" name="Click"/>
    <input type="text" id="fname" />
```